# UIButton title doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

В сториборде создал 2 кнопки. Назначил им title (через все тот же storyboard). Привязал @IBAction к каждой кнопке, но почему-то пишет, что title - nil.  Если же задавать программно title, то после клика по кнопке не возникает ошибки. Как это можно исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func firstBtnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.setTitle("Tapped", for: .normal)
        print(sender.title(for: .normal)!)
    }
    
    @IBAction func secondBtnTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.title(for: .normal)!)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Нужно просто откатиться на iOS ниже 15.